# Test class for setting same value to two diferents objects

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

Need help doing test class for this code part! how to do this in a test class

I tried creating the account and equals to the other object.

```
for (Account YieldU : AccountList){
           YieldU.Yield__c = a.Yield__c;
           YieldU.Yield2__c = a.Yield2__c;
          ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much context to what you're trying to do but you have to create the account

```
Account acct = new Account();
acct.Yield__c = 50;
acct.Yield2__c = 60;
insert acct;
```

Comment: I already did it, Let me try to explain me better,

I Have to objects, Account (Standard) And Gym(Custom), I do a For loop to equals a Value from Account to Gym, Like this:

for(Account temp : AccountList )
    {
        Gym Account2 = new Gym();
        Account2.Gym__c = temp.Id;
        Account2.bike__c = temp.Bike__c;
        Account2.m2_total__c = temp.m2_total__c;
        Account2.m2_fitness_group__c = temp.m2_fitness_group__c;
        Account2.active = temp.active;
        Insert Account2;
    }

Comment: Update your question with what you've done and more code to give more context

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand in your code 'a' will also be one object so firstly insert a record for that object.

```
abc__c ab= new abc__c();
ab.Yield__c = 10;
ab.Yield2__c = 20;
insert ab;

Account acct = new Account();
acct.Yield__c = ab.Yield__c;
acct.Yield2__c = ab.Yield2__c;
insert acct;
```

Comment: I already did it, Let me try to explain me better,

I Have to objects, Account (Standard) And Gym(Custom), I do a For loop to equals a Value from Account to Gym, Like this:

for(Account temp : AccountList )
    {
        Gym Account2 = new Gym();
        Account2.Gym__c = temp.Id;
        Account2.bike__c = temp.Bike__c;
        Account2.m2_total__c = temp.m2_total__c;
        Account2.m2_fitness_group__c = temp.m2_fitness_group__c;
        Account2.active = temp.active;
        Insert Account2;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
list<account> acclist = new list<account>();
    list<Gym__c> gmlist = new list<Gym__c>();
    Account acct = new Account();
    acct.Bike__c= abc;
    acct.m2_total__c = xyz;
    acct.m2_fitness_group__c = def;
    acct.active = true;
    insert acct;
    acclist.add(acct);
    for (account ac:acclist)
    {
        gym__c gm=new gym();
        gm.gym_id__c= ac.id;
        gm.bike__c = ac.bike__c;
        gm.m2_total__c = ac.m2_total__c;
        gm.m2_fitness_group__c = ac.m2_fitness_group__c;
        gm.active__c = ac.active__c;
        gmlist.add(gm);

    }
    insert gmlist;
```

if then also you did not get your result then please share your whole code with me.